# Looking for C++ Regex optionally including whitespaces

Tags: regex, escaping, whitespace, sequence

I'm having a string like

```
"<firstname>Anna</firstname>"
```

or

```
"<firstname>Anna Lena</firstname>"
```

and I want to use Regex to get the name out of it (so only "Anna" or "Anna Lena"). Currently I'm using:

```
std::regex reg1 ("(<firstname>)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(</firstname>)");
```

and

```
std::regex_replace (std::back_inserter(result), input.begin(), input.end(), reg1, "$2");
```

which works well with only one name, but apparently it misses anything after that because it doesn't consider whitespaces. Now I've tried adding `\s` like `((([a-zA-Z0-9]*)|\s)*)` but my IDE (Qt) tells me, that that `\s` is an unknown escape sequence.
Right now, `"<firstname>Anna Lena</firstname>"` results in `"<firstname>Anna"`.

How do I solve this in an elegant way?

Comment: `std::regex reg1("(<firstname>)([a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*)(</firstname>)");` or `std::regex reg1(R"((<firstname>)([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*)(</firstname>))");`

Comment: Results remain the same...

Comment: [Here](https://ideone.com/fHdqn7) it is working well. I removed the capturing groups from the firstname tags, and got the `match[1]` Group 1 value. Why do you mention Qt while you are using `std::regex`? What exactly are you using? Please share the full relevant code

Comment: Could you please show the whole relevant code? I think the problem is not just with the regex. I suggest using `regex_search` or `regex_match`, but I guess you have a vector of strings, and you want to modify this vector.

Answer (score 0):

Use a *reluctant* quantifier for dot:

```
std::regex reg1 ("<firstname>(.*?)</firstname>");
```

Alternately, you can use "not a right angle":

```
std::regex reg1 ("<firstname>[^<]*</firstname>");
```

Note that I removed the unnecessary groups around the tag literals, so the target is now group 1 (your regex captured it in group 2).

Comment: `std::regex reg1 ("<firstname>(.*?)</firstname>");` grabs "<firstname>Anna" and nothing if there's only one name; same goes for "not a right angle". Maybe I'm doing something wrong that's very basic...?

Comment: @saf here's a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/6ve4mPqxXH) of the regex capturing "Anna Lena" as group 1.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you have an issue with the `back_converter` in a `regex_replace` that inserts [*new elements automatically at the end of the container*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/).

I suggest adding `\s` to the character class and matching the strings instead of reassigning the vector strings.

Here is a [demo of my approach](https://ideone.com/nnms6z):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> strings;
    strings.push_back("<firstname>Anna</firstname>");
    strings.push_back("<firstname>Anna Lena</firstname>");
    std::regex reg("(<firstname>)([a-zA-Z0-9\\s]*)(</firstname>)");
    for (size_t k = 0; k < strings.size(); k++)
    {
        smatch s;
        if (std::regex_match(strings[k], s, reg)) {
            strings[k] = s[2];
            std::cout << strings[k] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Anna
Anna Lena
```